# I suspect that re.match messing up control flow

Tags: python, regex, match

Is there any way that regular expression match inside a if block would interfere with the code inside an else block?

In the following code, I have 100 test strings that are being inputed as `job_name` that should be appended to my `del_job_ids` array. Only 99 of them are being appended.

```
for j in jobs:
     name = jobs[j]['Job_Name'][0]       
     p=re.compile("(\\w*):?\\w*-?\\d*")
     if ((':' in name) or ('-' in name)):
         name=p.match(name).group(1)
     else:
         #if name==job_name and state!='C':
         #print "ok" 
         #del_job_ids.append(j)
         pass
     if name==job_name and state!='C':
         del_job_ids.append(j)
         name=None
```

If I comment out the line name=p.match(name).group(1), the one case that doesn't get appended before now get appended. I can also append that job by uncommmenting the code in the else block (the string passes the conditon for getting appended).

The difference between the strings is that 99 of them have colon, dashes, or both and the one other string has neither. I tested the regex multiple times. The string without dashes or colons should go the else clause and use the 'default' name defined at the top of the for loop.

Comment: Please post a few of the example strings that work, and the one string that doesn't.

Comment: Works: training_2-1, training_2:o-25, Training_2:a; Doesn't: training_2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're doing some very odd things here. Let's go through a few of them.

1 - `name = jobs[j]['Job_Name'][0]`

It seems to me that perhaps jobs is a container of dictionaries, which have a key 'Job_Name', and that key's value is a list or tuple. I think what you might mean is:

`name = j['Job_name'][0]`

If jobs is just a list of strings, being job names, all you need is this:
`name = j`, which you can just skip - and just use `j` when you want to refer to it.

2 - `p=re.compile("(\\w*):?\\w*-?\\d*")`

You're compiling your regex every time you go through the loop, where it is exactly the same each time, and you use it exactly **once**. Do this compilation **before** the loop begins.

3 - You don't need your else clause at all. And if you want "else if" in Python, you use "elif".

4 - Your regex could be simplified by using a **raw** string to eliminate all the double escapes: `p=re.compile(r"(\w*):?\w*-?\d*")`

5 - Your whole regex may be unnecessary. If you're doing what I think you're doing, you just want what appears before the first colon, if there is one. (Unless you really mean `group(1)`, which I think you don't.) Which means you could skip the regex (since you're matching with `in` anyhow), and just use something like `name = name.split(':')[0]`

Answer (score 2):

```
name=p.match(name).group(1)
```

You're changing what `name` is. That probably makes this false:

```
if name==job_name and state!='C':
```

Which makes this statement not execute:

```
del_job_ids.append(j)
```

I suggest taking a look at what `name` is after the `name.p.match(name).group(1)` statement.

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something ... Each time the for loop runs, name should be updated. Also, the case that doesn't get appended is handled by the else block.

Comment: @thaiyoshi - All of the code in your `else` block is commented out.

Comment: It's supposed to be commented out. The else block is just for testing. The else case should use name = jobs[j]['Job_Name'][0].

Comment: @thaiyoshi - My point is that you're changing `name`, which makes `name==job_name and state!='C'` be `False`, so it doesn't execute that block. You need to figure out what `name` is at that point and why it doesn't match that statement. The problem isn't the regex, it's the rest of the logic in the code.

Answer (score 2):

```
 for j in jobs:
      name = jobs[j]['Job_Name'][0]
```

This part doesn't make sense to me.  If 'jobs' is an iterable, then the first time through the loop, 'j' is set to 'jobs[0]', the next time it's set to 'jobs[1]', etc.  So using 'j' to index into 'jobs' is crazy talk.  You're saying "give me the next element from the iterable 'jobs', then use that element as an index into 'jobs'.

Comment: Good point. I suspect `jobs` is a dictionary, so what they really want is `for job in jobs.values(): name = job["Job_Name"][0]` (of course, `job["Job_Name"][0]` hints at even more problems..)

Answer (score 1):

The *match()* won't "interfere" with an else-clause.

The most likely cause here is that the `name==job` condition is failing for one of your test cases.

A judicious use of print-statements will likely will show which string is skipped. Or you an use *pdb*.

Comment: The one case that doesn't pass gets handled by the else clause. Putting the name==job condition inside the else clause makes it pass.